# SQL query pulling hardcoded records and amounts all with the same WHERE conditions

Tags: mysql

I have a car database and I am trying to pull **one** of each make and model of cars. Example: There are three Toyota Corollas, four Honda Civics and five Acura RSX. The query should return one Toyota Corolla, one Honda Civic and one Acura RSX. I can code this however there is a lot of repetition of code in the query.

```
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        main
    WHERE
        ( make_name = 'TOYOTA' AND model_name = 'CELICA' AND chassis = 'GT4' )
        AND
        mileage <= 100000
        AND
        rate >= '3.5'
        AND
        ( year >= 1990 and year <= 1998 )
    ORDER BY
        auction_date DESC,
        rate DESC
    LIMIT
        1
)
UNION
(
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        main
    WHERE
        ( make_name = 'NISSAN' AND model_name = 'SKYLINE' AND chassis = 'R33' )
        AND
        mileage <= 100000
        AND
        rate >= '3.5'
        AND
        ( year >= 1990 and year <= 1998 )
    ORDER BY
        auction_date DESC,
        rate DESC
    LIMIT
        1
)
```

So this will pull one Toyota Celica GT4 and one Nissan Skyline R33. But I repeat the conditions of mileage, rate and year for each car. This query has two cars I need but essentially I will be adding more in over time so I would like a way to add to this query without repeating the WHERE condition for each car since they will always be the same.

Comment: Which columns are you interested in seeing?

Comment: Can you put a http://sqlfiddle.com up with that base table and some sample data?

Answer (score 1):

**SQL Statement**

```
select 
*
from
(
SELECT make_name,
model_name,
chassis,
max(concat(auction_date,rate)) as mc
from main 
where
mileage <= 100000
        AND
        rate >= '3.5'
        AND
        ( year >= 1990 and year <= 1998 )  
group by
make_name, model_name, chassis 

) as a,
main as m
where a.make_name =m.make_name AND
a.model_name = m.model_name AND
a.chassis = m.chassis AND
a.mc = concat(m.auction_date,m.rate);
```

**Explanation**

This uses a derived table containing the distinct combinations of `make_name`, `model_name`, and `chassis`, as well as the `MAXIMUM auction_date+rate` .

I use the `MAXIMUM auction_date+rate` since we have the requirement is to get a only one ROW for each make_name, model_name, and chassis, but to get that row that has the LATEST auction_date, and highest rate.

This produces the derived table with results:

```
MAKE_NAME      MODEL_NAME   CHASSIS         MC
NISSAN         SKYLINE       GT4        0005-06-0117
NISSAN         SKYLINE       R33        0002-04-011
TOYOTA         CELICA        GT4        0005-01-0117
```

I then join this derived table with the main table, but with the conditions:

```
where a.make_name =m.make_name AND
a.model_name = m.model_name AND
a.chassis = m.chassis AND
a.mc = concat(m.auction_date,m.rate);
```

In this way, the rows are extracted that have the make, model, and chassis with the latest aucion date, and highest rate (But only one row for each make, model, and chassis).

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b5c8/2

**Update**

> I want to specify in the SQL which unique models I want. Which was why
>   I went: WHERE model_name='GT4' etc..

You can do this using multiple `OR` statements or using `CONCAT` and `IN` (or simply `IN`).

So, you either append at the end:

```
 AND 
 (
  (m.model_name='CELICA' AND m.chassis='GT4') OR
  (m.model_name='TEST' AND m.chassis='TEST')
);
```

or you append:

```
AND concat(m.model_name,'-',m.chassis) in ('CELICA-GT4','SKYLINE-GT4');
```

See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6fc09/2 that has both examples.

Comment: Cant get that to work, how does it pull one of each? I need to specify specific models hard-coded.

Comment: meewoK I appreciate all of this work you've done and it works on my dataset. However, I don't want all unique models in the database, there are over 6,000. I want to specify in the SQL which unique models I want. Which was why I went: WHERE model_name='GT4' etc.. Your method definitely works but I need to limit it to a few cars only that I hardcode in.

Comment: aha, you can make use of concat and IN function.. will update soon. meanwhile see: http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/in.php

Comment: trying these queries and I understand what you are doing but they all return an empty set. Still finding out why.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using a `LIMIT` clause to restrict the number of rows returned, and because the `LIMIT` clause gets evaluated last (or very nearly last) in the execution plan, the `WHERE` clause gets evaluated before the `LIMIT`, so that WHERE clause has to be repeated in each query.

There are other approaches to returning an equivalent resultset which would avoid repeating some of the conditions in the where clause, but they won't be as efficient, and they won't be able to make use of the `ORDER BY ... LIMIT ...` construct to restrict the rows returned.

Comment: In Oracle or MSSQL there's a RANK (or ROW_NUMBER) function for these use cases, but not in mySQL.